# Increase indexOf() value by one

Tags: javascript, arrays, repeat, indexof

I need to repeat each letter in an array of letters in such a way:
for example [a, b, c, d] => a, bb, ccc, dddd

My guess there is something wrong with this part: splitStr.indexOf(x) + 1)

Could you please have a look and give me a hint on what's wrong here? Thanks. (The final result should be A-Bb-Ccc-Dddd as a string)

```js
function accum(s) {
  var splitStr = s.toLowerCase().split('') // [a, b, c, d]
  var arr = splitStr.map(x => x.repeat(splitStr.indexOf(x) + 1)) // [a, bb, ccc, ddd]
  arr = arr.map(a => a.slice(0, 1).toUpperCase() + a.slice(1).toLowerCase())
  return arr.join('-')
}
console.log(accum('abcd'))
```

Comment: You snippet seems okey, the result is `A-Bb-Ccc-Dddd`?

Comment: You can use the second parameter of the `map`'s callback: `.map((x, i) => x.repeat(i + 1)) `

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the index argument of  `map()` callback and save looking for it again in the array.

You can also consolidate this into one `map()` instead of two

```js
function accum(s) {
  var splitStr = s.toLowerCase().split('') // [a, b, c, d]
  var arr = splitStr.map((x, i) => x.toUpperCase() + x.repeat(i));     
  return arr.join('-')
}
console.log(accum('abcd'))
```

Comment: Oh! Thanks a lot! Now I understand what I should have done there. And also thanks for showing me how I could combine those two map()s into one.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `index` argument (the second one) of the [Array.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) callback and save performance doing the uppercase inside the the first `map()` too.

```js
function accum(s)
{
    var splitStr = s.toLowerCase().split('');
    var arr = splitStr.map((x, idx) => x.toUpperCase() + x.repeat(idx));    
    return arr.join('-')
}

console.log(accum('abcd'));
```

```css
.as-console {background-color:black !important; color:lime;}
.as-console-wrapper {max-height:100% !important; top:0;}
```

Alternatively, you can approach the same using [String.replace()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) and the [replacement function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Specifying_a_function_as_a_parameter):

```js
function accum(s)
{
    return s.toLowerCase().replace(/./g, (match, offset) =>
    {
        let token = offset < s.length - 1 ? "-" : "";
        return match.toUpperCase() + match.repeat(offset) + token;
    });
}

console.log(accum('abcd'));
```

```css
.as-console {background-color:black !important; color:lime;}
.as-console-wrapper {max-height:100% !important; top:0;}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [repeat()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/repeat). It returns a new string which contains the specified number of copies of the string on which it was called, concatenated together.

```
 var list = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'];
 var result = Array.from(list, (v, i) => {
                  let value = v.repeat(i + 1);
                  return value.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + value.slice(1)
                 }).join('-');
 console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can map and join like this:

```
var s = 'AbCd';
var array1 = s. toLowerCase().split(''); //['a','b','c','d'];
const map1 = array1.map((x, index) => x.toUpperCase() + x.repeat(index)).join('-');

console.log(map1);
```

Comment: I didn't vote on this, but maybe people downvote an answer that is for all practical purposes identical to one posted several minutes earlier. Why not just upvote charlietfl's if this is the way to go?

Comment: Maybe that's why. I posted mine before refreshing and seeing his. Just didn't bother proofing his after the fact and then, in turn, deleting mine after identifying similarities.  Is that standard protocol?

Comment: @MarkMeyer The first version of the answer you refers only contemplates the usage of `index` on the `map()` callback, he edited it after to improve, while my first version and this one contemplates also other things. So i'm forced to made a fast answer to get upvotes? Also sometimes, while you are making an answer you aren't looking if new ones comes in. I don't think that is a good reason to downvote unless there are more than 10 or 15 minutes between answers.

Comment: @Shidersz it was just a hypothesis.